# How to print table header on every page when generating docx?

Tags: php, docx, opentbs

My template is simple. Table header and:

> [a.name;block=w:tr]   [a.version] [a.description]

I managed to create a table, but I am wonder if I can repeat table header on every document page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can repeat the first row of the table on each page using the Ms Word property.

Select the first line of the table, open the Table properties and chose the "Row" tab.
If the first row is selected, then you can check the box "Repeat as header row on the top f each page".

Of course [OpenTBS](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php) keeps this property, so that you will have it when the table is expanded with data.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but without luck, maybe I should try more ;)

Comment: I've tested, it worked for me. Do you have a template that we can test?